# Sending Emails without User Intervention

Tags: android

I really neeeed help on this b.c it is silly. I have seen this code and it says that it work properly as in the following link :http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android

MY Question is: As a starter How can I use this code in eclipse?! do I copy it in to the .java file? and what about the layout!

and on where should I write my own email and password! Or where i should include this?

Comment: You really need to start with basic programming and android programming before asking broad questions like this. read the android documentation [HERE](http://developer.android.com) and some great beginner tutorials [HERE](http://www.vogella.com)

Comment: Thanks for replaying, my problem is this is a project i need to work on at uni, and this part is only a part of it, I just need to know how to run this code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Copy the java code to your activity

```
Mail m = new Mail("gmailusername@gmail.com", "password");
```

you could see this line where you need to enter email id and password

```
  String[] toArr = {"bla@bla.com", "lala@lala.com"};
```

here enter to which id you want to send mail

```
  m.setTo(toArr); 
  m.setFrom("wooo@wooo.com");
```

here enter what mail id should be used from column of mail

```
  m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
  m.setBody("Email body.");
```

above line is used for adding subject and body to mail

you have to create XML file according to your wish with button with id `send_email`

Comment: @downvote, can i know why did you give downvote ?

Answer (score 2):

You really need to start from most beginning of Android Development. Go to developer's web site and you will find plenty of useful tutorials.

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html